# Windows.System.LaunchUriAsync throws exception only on Windows 10 mobile

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am developing a UWP app which is targeted on both Desktop and Mobile.
At some point in the app the following code is used

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri), new Windows.System.LauncherOptions { ContentType = mimeType });
```

This code works as it should on Desktop. For example when the URI is that of an image (like this one https://support.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/pigeony.jpg that I have tried) the Photos app is launched and the photo is displayed.

On mobile however the exact same code, with the exact same arguments throws an Exception.

> Message: The method or operation is not implemented
>
> StackTrace:       at
>   Windows.System.LauncherOptions.put_ContentType(String value)    at
>   MyApp.Services.PresentationService.d__7.MoveNext()

The problem seems to be with the LauncherOptions because if I remove them from the call the image opens normally in the browser. (However this is not acceptable functionality, I need to launch the appropriate application).

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) there should be no differences between windows 10 and windows 10 mobile concerning the LaunchUriAsync method. Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you debug in an emulator? Also, what build are you running on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to documentation there should be no differences between windows 10 and windows 10 mobile concerning the LaunchUriAsync method

Actually, the `LauncherOptions.ContentType` property is only implemented on Desktop devices, see Remark in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcheroptions.contenttype.aspx)

> Important  This property is only implemented on Desktop devices.

-

> However this is not acceptable functionality, I need to launch the appropriate application

Currently, there is no simple/direct way to implement this on Mobile, there are some workarounds, for example: Download Images to Local folder/Picture folder, opening Photo apps or showing them in your app

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
var df = Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily;
if (df == "Windows.Desktop")
{
            options.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
}
else
{
            //Omitted, save network images into Picture folder

            uriToLaunch = "ms-photos:///"; //Launch Photo app
}
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
// Launch the URI with the content type
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

BTW, please submit your feature request using the **Feedback** app, this is a good way to let MS know what users/developers need.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Franklin, it totally eluded me.  I'll save to temp folder since I don't need the images to persist. I also submitted the feature request.